# "Supposed" versus "expected"

Tags: word-choice, adjectives

What is the difference between *supposed* and *expected*?

For example, which one should  be used in the following example?

> I am confused about the two words *base* and *basis*. I often use one when
>   the other is **expected/supposed**.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/77563/base-versus-basis

Comment: @Henry: Nice catch. Kudo to those hanging around both sites.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To [suppose](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/suppose) something means:

> **1.** to assume (something), as for the sake of argument or as part of a proposition or theory: *Suppose the distance to be one mile.*
>   **2.** to consider (something) as a possibility suggested or an idea or plan proposed: *Suppose we wait until tomorrow.*
>   **3.** to believe or assume as true; take for granted: *It is supposed that his death was an accident.*
>   **4.** to think or hold as an opinion: *What do you suppose he will do?*

To [expect](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/expect) something means:

> **1.** to look forward to; regard as likely to happen; anticipate the occurrence or the coming of: *I expect to read it. I expect him later. She expects that they will come.*
>   **2.** to look for with reason or justification: *We expect obedience.*
>   **3.** *Informal.* to suppose or surmise; guess: *I expect that you are tired from the trip.*

*Suppose* implies a guess (not what you necessarily think will happen), while *expect* means that you are pretty sure it will/should happen.

So *expect* is better in your example:

> I often use one when the other is expected.

However, even that implies that a certain person is expecting one or the other, rather than that one or the other would actually fit better.  I would say:

> I often use one when the other would fit better.

Answer (score 2):

I've never seen *supposed* without being followed by *to* in such a construction. Generally speaking, *supposed* is never left without *to* when it has the sense of *expected*. In the example you cite, I'd go for *expected*, though *correct* would be a better choice.

As for the difference between the two words, they are sometimes used interchangeably:

*He isn't expected/supposed to arrive before 9.*

However, this isn't always the case, esp with some fixed phrases, like:

*How am I supposed to know what you wanted me to do?*

OR

*What is that supposed to mean?*

*expected* would sound unnatural in these examples.